# How to condense an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of orders below and would like to condense it by name and then have an array of all the items that person has ordered

```
const orders = [
  { name: 'Tedd', item: 'coke', },
  { name: 'Louise', item: 'burger' },
  { name: 'Louise', item: 'chips' },
  { name: 'David', item: 'chips' },
  { name: 'David', item: 'burger' },
  { name: 'David', item: 'coke' }
]
```

how i want it to look

```
[
  { name: 'Tedd', item: ['coke'] },
  { name: 'Louise', item: ['burger', 'chips'] },
  { name: 'David', item: ['chips', 'burger', 'coke'] }
]
```

I tried this

```
      const out = [...new Set(orders.map(i => i.name))].map(i => {
        return { name: i, item: orders.reduce((a, b) => [a.item].concat([b.item])) }
      })
```

but it just concatenates all the orders

```
[
  { name: 'Tedd', item: ['chips', 'burger', 'coke'] },
  { name: 'Louise', item: ['chips', 'burger', 'coke'] },
  { name: 'David', item: ['chips', 'burger', 'coke'] }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the array down to an object with name as the key and the collected items as the
values ,then run a map on the keys of the object to return the required array.

```
const obj = orders.reduce((map, order) => {
const { name } = order;
if (map[name]) {
  map[name].push(order.item);
} else {
  map[name] = [order.item];
}
return map}, {})
const output = Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({name:key,item:obj[key]}))
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) may be useful for this particular problem.

```js
orders.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const personIndex = acc.findIndex((item) => item.name === curr.name);
    if (personIndex === -1) {
      acc.push({ name: curr.name, item: [curr.item] });
    } else {
      acc[personIndex].item.push(curr.item);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` and build an object. If same name as key exist then push to existing array. Get `Object.values` from this build object.

```js
const condence = arr => {
  const all = {};
  arr.forEach(({name, item}) => {
    all[name] ||= {name, item: []};
    all[name].item.push(item);
  })
  return Object.values(all);
}

const orders = [
  { name: 'Tedd', item: 'coke', },
  { name: 'Louise', item: 'burger' },
  { name: 'Louise', item: 'chips' },
  { name: 'David', item: 'chips' },
  { name: 'David', item: 'burger' },
  { name: 'David', item: 'coke' }
]

console.log(condence(orders))
```